# Delphi Indy HTTP + REST API with Token Certificate

Tags: rest, web-services, delphi, indy, idhttp

I'm currently working on a connection with a REST API Web Service using Indy HTTP, but I'm having some trouble with Authentication, via Browser I connect using a SafeNet Token Certificate, but when using a IdHTTP.Get I get error 401 Unauthorized.

I'm using Indy 10.54.38.
I've set IdHTTP.HTTPOptions hoInProcessAuth and hoForceEncodeParams True.
I'm generating a JSON on a StringStream and sending on the GET, but I believe the main problem is the Token Certificate, I get the same problem trying to connect with Fiddler.

Here follows my code:

```
URL := 'https://portalunico.siscomex.gov.br/due/api/ext/due/consultarDadosResumidosDUE';
  JsonStreamEnvio := TStringStream.Create(Memo1.Text);
  StrList := TStringList.Create();
  StrList.LoadFromStream(JsonStreamEnvio);
  Memo2.Text := StrList.Text;

  // Init request:
  try
    idHttp.Request.Clear;
    idHttp.Request.ContentType := 'application/json';
    idHttp.Request.BasicAuthentication := true;
    idHttp.Request.UserAgent   := 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.96 Safari/537.36';
    idHttp.Request.AcceptEncoding := 'gzip, deflate';
    idHttp.Request.AcceptLanguage := 'pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4';
    idHttp.Request.CacheControl := 'no-cache';


    idHttp.Response.ContentType := 'application/json';

    idHttp.Get(URL, JsonStreamEnvio);

   finally
     memo1.Lines.LoadFromStream(JsonStreamEnvio);
   end;
```

Comment: Indy knows nothing about your SafeNet certificate. You will have to set the `TIdHTTP.Request.BasicAuthentication` property to false and then populate the `TIdHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Authorization']` property with the necessary credentials manually.

Comment: Are there any guides on how I should fill the custom headers?
I know you can fill your token key there, do I need more info? Such as password, name, etc

Comment: I can't answer that, because I don't know how SafeNet interacts with HTTP authentication, or even how it interacts with a web browser.  Does it even work at the HTTP layer, or does it operate at the SSL/TLS layer instead? I have no clue.

Comment: I believe it operates on SSL/TLS layer, it's a A3 Certificate in Token format, I've tried exporting it to .cer for use on Indy but without success since I can't export its private keys